# No valid interface language found on Photoshop CS on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

I downloaded Photoshop CS (Photoshop 8) for Windows 7. When I tried to open it I get the follow error message:

> No valid interface language is present

How do I fix this?

Comment: Photoshop CS8 ???? Man, time flies, the last version I've heard of is the CS4 !!!

Comment: Windows 7 **doubles** your productivity !

Comment: Joke aside, which version of photoshop do you really use, what do you mean by "downloaded" ? Is that a trial version or something ?

Comment: Folks stop downvoting him, please. His question is pertinent and well formulated. It just so happens most photoshop localized versions don't have this problem, so its natural we don't know about it. It's however a common problem with the Arabic versions.

Comment: @Gnoupi; I believe you can download a purchased copy straight off adobe.com.

Comment: *Sigh*. Do I need to start *another* rant? (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26305/why-dont-stack-overflow-users-still-know-how-to-close-questions-appropriately/27313#27313)

Comment: @A Dwarf, I'm sorry, but even if his question is pertinent, it lacks details and any basic formatting or punctuation. This is not what I would call a "well formulated question".

Comment: @gnoupi: please don't expect everyone to have the same knowledge of the english language, or to be as well educated in it as yourself. The original question, which you can still see from the edit history) is of easy comprehension. This is all it should take.

Comment: @A Dwarf: The original question was unclear, and lacking details. Hopefully this error message in google turned the answer, but besides, you didn't know anything on what exact version, nor even the language of it. I don't "expect people" to have same knowledge of english language, but I expect people who want some help to actually make the effort too. Fact is, on SuperUser, answerers are ready to interpolate any badly asked question just to answer as fast as possible. So indeed, why would people asking question make any effort, people are here to decipher their requests.

Comment: If not for the back and forth of these comments, this question would still be very unclear and not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 8):

This is a problem with the **Arabic** versions of Photoshop.

You may want to [check the solution found on an Arabic forum](http://www.rt1111.com/vb/showthread.php?p=82774) which *roughly* translates to this:

- After the install, open up the Control Panel
- Open up Region and Language
- The following dialog will appear:

  [image: Photoshop dialog in Arabic]
- Follow the numbered steps to switch language to English (United States).
- Restart Photoshop.

Comment: I can read Arabic and this is actually the solution of this problem. That link talks about version 8 of Photoshop, and I think this is what the OP is asking about. Great find. +1

Comment: Great edit, Eight, clear and giving the actual answer without following a link.

Comment: It be even better if someone with arabic knowledge could translate that image.

Comment: According to the formats shown, I would guess it says to switch language and region to English(US). (Then to click apply, and then ok, which could be shortened in ok only).

Comment: (After further checking, "United States" is indeed written between the parenthesis)